# How to merge cells in apex:panelGrid?

Tags: visualforce, table, panelgrid

I do not want to resort to HTML. How to merge cells in `<apex:panelGrid>`?

The below diagram shows column span merge using HTML tables. How to do both, column and row span merge, using Visualforce components only?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't merge the cells. But you can play with `columns` parameter and nesting another panel grid into the first one, but with a different columns number. Here is my example:

```
<style>
.colClass{
    width:50%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.myHeader {
    background: #cecece;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all" frame="box">
    <!-- The first column -->
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all">
        <!-- Output panel used to be able to layout the row -->
        <apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block" styleClass="myHeader">
            <apex:outputText value="Header 1"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <!-- Another header column -->
        <apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block" styleClass="myHeader">
            <apex:outputText value="Header 2"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all" columnClasses="colClass">
            <apex:outputText value="Text 1"/>
            <apex:outputText value="Text 2"/>
        </apex:panelGrid> 

        <apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block">
            <apex:outputText value="Text 3"/>  
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:panelGrid>

    <!-- Merged header -->
    <apex:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:100%;" styleClass="myHeader">
        <apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block">
            <apex:outputText value="Header 3"/>  
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:panelGroup>

    <apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all" columnClasses="colClass">
        <apex:outputText value="Text 4"/>
        <apex:outputText value="Text 5"/>
    </apex:panelGrid>             

</apex:panelGrid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Be aware that nesting Visualforce elements like apex:panelGrid is not advised from a viewstate perspective. I do not recall which tutorial I watched/read/etc, but I do remember that salesforce.com was against using Visualforce elements when a normal element would suffice. In this specific case, since they want a custom table, normal HTML is more appropriate than an apex:panelGrid or nested elements.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use spanning columns in an apex:panelGrid. You should instead use a normal HTML table. Nesting managed elements (those with a namespace like apex or c) will bloat your view state size unnecessarily.